# installing Postgis 1.5.2 with PostGres 9.0.3 fails

Tags: postgis

on Mac OS X Snow Leopard, I get the following error on make

```
gcc -g -O2  -fno-common -DPIC  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes stringbuffer.o shpopen.o dbfopen.o safileio.o getopt.o shp2pgsql-core.o shp2pgsql-cli.o ../liblwgeom/liblwgeom.a -o shp2pgsql -liconv -lm 
Undefined symbols:
  "_libiconv_open", referenced from:
      _utf8 in shp2pgsql-core.o
  "_libiconv_close", referenced from:
      _utf8 in shp2pgsql-core.o
      _utf8 in shp2pgsql-core.o
  "_libiconv", referenced from:
      _utf8 in shp2pgsql-core.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [shp2pgsql] Error 1
make: *** [loaderdumper] Error 2
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's some problem with [libconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). Either it isn'l installed  or it isn't correctly linked. Try installing it first.